# Cancel ASIFormDataRequest in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

Hi. I am uploading images to a server using ASIFormDataRequest. I would like the option to cancel uploading images, so I am attempting to cancel all uploading requests, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my code:

```
if (asiRequest) {
    NSLog(@"cancel call");
    [asiRequest cancel];
    asiRequest.delegate = nil;
    asiRequest.uploadProgressDelegate = nil;
    asiRequest = nil;
    progressbar.hidden=YES;
    uploadinglbl.hidden=YES;
    photosCountlbl.hidden=YES;
    [self.spinner stopAnimating];

    //[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Can anyone help with how I may be able to cancel all requests?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(![asiRequest isCancelled]) {
 // Cancels an asynchronous request
 [asiRequest cancel];
 // Cancels an asynchronous request, clearing all delegates and blocks first
 [asiRequest clearDelegatesAndCancel];
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for response but here ASIFormDataRequest don't have "clearDelegatesAndCancel" it show me error

Comment: It definitely exists. Check this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795233/iphone-stop-an-asiformdatarequest) for the same question.